# Convert Enum to string in c#

Tags: c#

I have an `enum` class. I am using *C#*. I need to convert it from `enum` to `string`. For example, Language.En will return as `string`.

```
public enum Language
{
    EN,
    SV,
    DE
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call ToString() on the Enum.

```
Language.EN.ToString();
```

Comment: @Ian specifying Culture/FormatProvider in `Enum.ToString` is deprecated/obsolete -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum.ToString.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this :)

using System;

enum Priority
{
    never,
    killed,
    beauty
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Write string representation for killed.
    Priority enum1 = Priority.killed;
    string value1 = enum1.ToString();

    // Loop through enumerations and write string representations
    for (Priority enum2 = Priority.never; enum2 <= Priority.beauty; enum2++)
    {
        string value2 = enum2.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(value2);
    }
    }
}

Output
never
killed
beauty
```